# Как посчитать число слов в строке?

Tags: c, строки

Дано натуральное число n и последовательность символов S1...Sn. Группы символов, разделены одним или несколькими пробелами, будем называть словами. Подсчитать кол-во слов в данной строке.

Comment: Для получения полезного ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему

Comment: Формат сайта не предполагает, что за вас будут полностью решать задачу. Предлагаю вам делать это самостоятельно и задавать вопросы по конкретным затруднениям и ошибкам.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Идея простая, число слов равно числе пробелов между словами + 1.
Вам надо учесть смежные пробелы и на них не реагировать.

Примерный алгоритм, детали и реализацию сделаете сами:

- Идете в цикле по строке, смотрите каждый символ
- Храните предыдущий символ (в начале он пустой)
- Если увидели пробел и прошлый символ НЕ пробел - увеличили счетчик слов
- Запоминаете прошлый символ
- Дошли до конца - если в конце пробел, то выходите, если символ - увеличиваете
  счетчик еще на 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 100 // Maximum string size

int main()
{
    char str[MAX_SIZE];
    int i, words;

    /* Input string from user */
    printf("Enter any string: ");
    gets(str);

    i = 0;
    words = 1;

    /* Runs a loop till end of string */
    while(str[i] != '\0')
    {
        /* If the current character(str[i]) is white space */
        if(str[i]==' ' || str[i]=='\n' || str[i]=='\t')
        {
            words++;
        }

        i++;
    }

    printf("Total number of words = %d", words);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]